# Trigonometry in integrating area of a surface

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the area of the surface of $y = \cos(\frac{1}{2})x$, $0 \leq x \leq \pi$    rotated about the x-axis.

$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{2} \sin(\frac{1}{2}x)$

$$\begin{align}
S &= 2\pi \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(\frac{1}{2}x)\sqrt{1 +\bigg( -\frac{1}{2}\sin(\frac{1}{2}x)\bigg)^2}dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(\frac{1}{2}x) \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{4} \sin^2(\frac{1}{2}x)}dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(\frac{1}{2}x) \sqrt{4 + \sin^2(\frac{1}{2}x)}dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt{4\cos(\frac{1}{2}x) + \sin^2(\frac{1}{2}x) \cos(\frac{1}{2}x)}dx
\end{align}$$

Here is where I am stuck. I don't see any form of trig manipulation that can help me here.

Also, did I set the problem up correctly up to this point? Thank you.

**Edit with additional work:**

$$\begin{align}
S &= 2\pi \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(\frac{x}{2}) \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{4} \sin^2(\frac{x}{2})}dx \\
\textrm{substitute u = $\sin(\frac{x}{2})$}&= 4\pi \int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt{1 + \frac{u^2}{4}}du \\
&= 4\pi \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sqrt{4+u^2}}{\sqrt{4}} \\
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt{4+u^2} \\
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt{4 + 2^2\tan^2\theta} \sec^2\theta d\theta \\
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt{4}\sqrt{sec^2\theta}sec^2\theta d\theta \\
&= 4\pi \int_{0}^{\pi} \sec^3\theta d\theta
\end{align}$$

From here, I know there are plenty of posts and wikipedia pages on how to integrate $\sec^3\theta$. I just would like to know that I did everything correctly up to this point.

Comment: Go back to the second or third line and make an appropriate $u$-substitution. Also, you have typos — like $\cos(\frac12)x$ instead of $\cos(\frac12 x)$ and $\sin^2(\frac12)$.

Comment: Can you verify whether you mean $\cos\left(\frac x2\right)$ or $\left(\cos \frac12\right)x$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Could you please confirm u-substitution is right now?

Comment: No, when you switch to the $u$ integral, you must change the limits of integration. You've done two different substitutions, so you have to change your limits twice! Also, please find a different letter. Your second $\theta$ is a totally different variable.

Comment: Oh, I thought that changing the limits of integration was "optional". Yes you are right, I did a regular substitution with $u$ and the second substitution is a trigonometric substitution with $\theta$, that is why the letter is different. 

Not sure if we are on the same page about that, but just wanted to check first before assuming anything

Answer (score 1):

On the third line, you forgot to divide by $2$ on the outside of the square root.

It should have been $\pi \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sqrt{4+\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\,dx$

Now, consider the u-substitution $u=\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$.

This will convert the integral to $\pi \displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}\sqrt{4+u^2}\,du$.

Now, use $u=2v$ and $du=2\,dv$  to convert the integral into $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\sqrt{2}\sqrt{4+4v^2}\,dv=\pi\int_0^\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+v^2}\,dv$

Now, consider using $\tan(\theta)$ to complete the integral.

Comment: Does OP know how to integrate sec^3(x)dx?

Comment: I've done it before...and I know it is a complicated integral to solve, but if I can get up to at least that point, I will be happy. Let me update with my work in the main post